# $filter si propiedad no existe. $aggregate

Tags: mongodb

Estoy tratando de filtrar un arreglo con esta estructura

```
{
          "ordenes": [
            {
              "_id": "XXXX",
              "prop0": [{}],
              "prop1": [],
              "prop2": {},
              "prop3": {}
            },
            {
                "prop0": [{}],
                "prop1": [],
                "prop2": {},
                "prop3": {}
            }
          ]
}
```

Usando este código:

```
{
    "$project": {
       "moreProp": "$moreProp" ,
       "ordenes": {
            "$filter": {
               "input": "$ordenes",
               "as": "orden",
               "cond": { "$ifNull": ["$$orden._id", true] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Necesito ignorar los elemento del arreglo que no tienen la propiedad `_id`, pero parece que no está funcionando con el código de arriba.

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

He estado probando tu Query y después de varios intentos he podido conseguir una solución que te podría ayudar a filtrar todos los subdocumentos que contenga `_id`.

Te muestro como lo he podido solucionar:

```
{
    $project:{
        pepe: {$type:"$_id"},
        orden:{
            $filter: {
               input:"$ordenes",
               as: "orden",
               cond: {
                  $eq:[ {$type:"$$orden._id"} , "objectId" ] 
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Al final lo que he realizado es comprobar en cada subdocumento si su campo `_id` es de tipo `objectId`.

He optado por un sentido opuesto a tu consulta, en vez de buscar nulos, busco lo que necesitas. Pienso que es un poco mas restrictiva ya que si algún subdocumento tiene un campo `_id` que no sea un `objectId` no te lo dejara pasar.

Ahora no se si te vendrá mejor o peor, todo dependerá de tu implementación.

Aun así espero haberte ayudado o darte alguna idea para encontrar tu solución.

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Me parece muy interesante tu aproximación. Pero la clave estaba en invertir la condición de `true` a `false`